# Can python 3 be used as scripting engine for an "ActiveX Scripting Host"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32, wsh

I have to convert an existing python 2.7.15 script to python 3.7.4.
The existing script is launched by an programm which is an 'ActiveX Scripting Host' and works fine.
The problem I encountered is that I can't get the API to use python 3 (I wrote a simple script which tells me which python version is used). As I understood pywin32 should register itself as scripting engine in the registry, but it looks like the programm only finds python 2. I tried uninstalling python 2 completely but python 3 was still not found.
Can python 3 even be used as scripting engine on windows? Or do I have to change some registry keys?
Thanks for any help regarding this!